# WCF or windows service to implement MSMQ

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, msmq

I have a client server setup where i am sending the messages to the server over http(I am using WCF service hosted as windows service.)In my current setup as I have seen some messages are lost when the connection is down between client and server ,for the sake of reliability i have decided to use MSMQ.So the client sends the messages to the queue and the server continuously polls the queue I need some design decision to be taken before i will developing.
Which one would be the best bet windows service or wcf service(hosted as windows service) ?

Are there any advantages apart from windows service which WCF has if i have to develop such a service where all it has to do is continuusly read messages from the queue  and does some processing.I would be using a private queue which is transnactional .

Comment: Look at NService bus.  It does exactly what you are trying to accomplish.  Pretty easy to setup as well.  http://nservicebus.com/

Comment: @JohnHartsock thank you but i want to write some thing on my own.

Comment: Why not just use your existing WCF service and use WS-ReliableMessaging ? If you are dead set on MSMQ, then you can use NetMSMQBinding for your transport layer but other HTTP based transport bindings are supported too.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest avoiding writing code that directly integrates with MSMQ and instead using an existing service bus to do that for you (like NServiceBus or MassTransit). Rolling-your-own messaging layer may work for the simplest of systems but as requirements change over time you will need a fuller featured service bus. The service buses that I mentioned do the following things in a developer friendly way:

- Messaging patterns (fire-and-forget, request-response, publish subscribe)
- Message serialization
- Message routing
- Failure/Retry logic (i.e. a message handler is supposed to update a database, but the database is down how do you handle this?)
- Long running processes (also called sagas)

These are just a few of the things you will be writing before long if you go the roll-your-own route.